# How antivirus companies create virus defnitions for new outbreaks

Tags: virus, antivirus

This question quite amazes me. I dont understand how antivirus companies get info about the latest viruses. have they installed some kind of filters to monitor the internet traffic ?
Or they are purely dependent on sites like **www.virustotal.com** and similar ? If thats the  case, then why some companies create a patch first, and other companies dont even know about that virus ?

Please clarify.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Various methods can be used:

- Samples are sent in by customers
- Malware detected by heuristic scanners (i.e. stuff that behaves like a virus) is further analysed
- Mail blocked as spam can be analysed for malware attachments.
- "honeypots", which are public servers or email addresses designed to collect malware
- going undercover in malware writers communities

Comment: Now I'm imagining new guys approaching malware communities having to so some "being evil" test before being accepted...